# setting cookie through curl

Tags: php, cookies, libcurl

I am trying to set cookie through cURL in PHP but it fails. my php code looks like this

```
$ch=curl_init();
$url="http://localhost/javascript%20cookies/test_cookies.html";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'user=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $contents;
?>
```

the file test_cookies.html contains javascript that checks for a cookie and if it finds it dispalys the content with additional user content.
but when i use the above script it displays the contents of the page test_cookies.html but not with the additional user content which means that it is not setting the cookie.

i tried writing another script like this

```
<?php
header("Set-Cookie:user=1");
header("Location:test_cookies.html");
?>
```

this works and sets the cookie and shows the additional user content too.
I also tried using

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");
```

this is writing the cookie information to the file but not reading it when fetching the page.
can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since javascript conducts the check in the browser, you should set the cookie before sending the output to the browser. So you need to combine both scripts:

```
$ch=curl_init();
$url="http://localhost/javascript%20cookies/test_cookies.html";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header("Set-Cookie:user=1");
echo $contents;
```

Explanation:
Please note that we are looking at two transfers here:

1. data is fetched by curl, and then
2. it is sent to the browser.

This is a special case where you are using curl to get the content from `localhost`, but in real-life uses you'd use curl to get content from a 3rd host.

If you receive different content based on whether a cookie is sent in the request or not, then you should set the cookie with curl. In most cases you can then send the content with no additional tweaking to the browser. But here, you make the decision with checking for a cookie *in the browser*, so you don't need the first cookie setting, and *you do need* the second one.

Comment: but sending a header with cookie informtion means i dont need to set the CURLOPT_COOKIE option. doesnt seem good to me.

Comment: I updated my answer after realizing the content fetched by curl does not depend on whether a cookie is present or not, so, you don't need the cookie when getting the html page by curl, but you do need it when the content arrives in the browser. This is what the above does. I would put feelings aside and do a test.

Comment: @Majid Fouladpour: but this way i am not using curl to set cookies but relying on header. what if i need to use curl? i used options like CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE AND CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR but he dont work too. isnt ther some way out?

Comment: Added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @Majid Fouladpour: i have changed my code and need your help.here is my new [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019793/html-page-not-getting-cookies-through-libcurl). please check it

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript will not work by getting page from curl.

Comment: then how would my html page check for cookies if i dont use javascript?

Comment: In PHP, look at $_COOKIE.  Your server side code can also interact with cookies, not just javascript.

Comment: Nowise, only if you have php page and checks it by $_COOKIES

Comment: @El yobo: but then i have to put the html in a php file. that might be a solution but can you please see whats wrong with the above code. I ve been stuck on this for too long and i cant c whats the problem?