# html page not getting cookies through libcurl

Tags: php, cookies, curl

i modified my previous code. you can see my previous post if your intersted [setting cookie through curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007225/setting-cookie-through-curl)
But here is a fresh beginning my new code looks linke this 
i have a php file using curl like this

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init();
$url="http://localhost/javascript%20cookies/test_cookies.php";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

the file ***test_cookies.php*** looks like this

```
<?php
if($_COOKIE['user']==1)
{
header("Set-Cookie:user=1; color=blue");
header("Location:http://localhost/javascript%20cookies/test_cookies.html");
}
?>
```

the file ***test_cookies.html*** has some javascript that checks for  cookies and if it finds those cookies then it displays the text accordingly.
the php file with curl code is sending the cookies and the ***test_cookies.php*** is setting the cookie and redirecting to the page ***test_cookies.html*** but this page is not receiving the cookies and thus it is not not showing the content accordingly.
can somebody tell me whats the problem now?

here are the headers i get displayed in firefox on setting CURLOPT_HEADER to true

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Mon, 16 May 2011 15:03:59 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.1 Set-Cookie: user=1; color=blue Location: http://localhost/javascript%20cookies/test_cookies.html Content-Length: 0 Content-Type: text/html HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 16 May 2011 15:03:59 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 Last-Modified: Mon, 16 May 2011 12:13:24 GMT ETag: "11000000013d0c-493-4a363950a70f3" Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 1171 Content-Type: text/html
```

you can see that there are two set of headers displayed.is this because i am making 2 calls to header?

Comment: Are you using raw HTTP headers instead of [setcookie()](http://es2.php.net/setcookie) for any reason?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: yes i am using calls to header functions(see my code above).is there any trouble with that?

Comment: Your PHP file would only set the cookie if the cookie exists in the first place. If the cookie doesn't exist or otherwise doesn't contain `1`, then no cookies will be set. So how does that `user` cookie get set in the first place?

Comment: @Marc B: i am setting the cookie through curl using the option CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE (look my first code segment). i have checked the text file it contains the cookie, so i am sure the cookie is reaching the file test_cookies.php and that is why the redirection is taking place to the html file

Comment: Well, setcookies() takes care of all the details: escaping values, formatting dates, getting the right format... There is no need to do it manually.

Comment: Use HTTPFox and/or Firebug to view the headers as they go between your browser and the initial curl script, see if the cookie headers show up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will now explain what i was trying to do.
i had an html page that asked for some verification code and then it sent that verification code to a php script which on verifying the code set a cookie and redirected to the same html page.
the html page had some externally linked javascript which on checking the cookie value displayed the content of the page with some tweaking.
i am now writing the code for this

the html file with content and form

> test_cookies.html

```
    //some css,javascript and html and then a form
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/javascript%20cookies/test_cookies.php">
```

the php file which verifies the code

> test_cookies.php

```
if($_POST['value']=="code")
setcookie("user",1);
if($_POST['value']!="code")
setcookie("user",1,time()-1);
header("Location:http://localhost/javascript%20cookies/test_cookies.html");
```

and now the php file with curl code

> curl_cookies.php

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init();
$url="http://localhost/javascript%20cookies/test_cookies.php";
$post="value=code";     //here i have hard-coded the pst value for a demo but i could have got this from the user
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$res=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match('/Location: (.*)\s/',$res,$location);
preg_match('/Set-Cookie: (.*)\s/',$res,$cookie);
$cookie=rtrim($cookie[0])."; path=/ ";         //path needed to be changed because curl_cookies.php and test_cookies.html are in different directories. 
header($cookie);
header($location[0]);
?>
```

this finally worked and the browser is displaying the tweaked content. this thing taught me a lot about http. 
Thanks to all who helped me when i was in dark.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve with the code. You'd get better help if you explain why you are doing this. It is probable that your *approach* is wrong and you could get the ultimate result with a different/simpler approach.

And now to answer your question, this is what happens:

1. From your browser, you send a GET request to `curl.php` (the name I use for your first file),
2. curl in that file checks `cookie.txt` and finds `user=1`, so it sends a GET request to `test_cookies.php` and sends the cookie with the request
3. `test_cookies.php` sees that `user=1` is true, so it sends a header to  `curl.php` and asks it to set two cookies: `user=1` and `color=blue` (for the first cookie this is pointless, user=1 is already set, but let's ignore this as no harm is done)
4. You have not set `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` option, so when `curl.php` receives the set cookie header it does not give a damn (nothing happens)
5. Next, `test_cookies.php` sends a redirect header to `curl.php`, since you have set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1`, `curl.php` sends another GET request, this time to get `test_cookies.html`
6. Content of `test_cookies.html` is returned to `curl.php`,
7. `curl_exec($ch);` causes the returned content (source of `test_cookies.html`) be echoed back to your browser,
8. Your browser parses what it received and the javascript is executed. It checks for a cookie named `user` and does not find one, so it displays content for when there is no cookie (because there isn't).

Now, you may wonder what happens if you add:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt");
```

What happens is that your `cookie.txt` will be updated in step 4 and will have two cookies; `user=1` and `color=blue`. But this does NOT give you the result you expect. Because `header("Set-Cookie:user=1; color=blue");` is instructing curl to set the cookie, and curl does this by storing the cookies in the file you specified in `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` option. So, even though you added that option, when you reach step 8 javascript will not find that cookie, because the browser you use does not know or care about your `cookie.txt`, it looks somewhere else to check if a cookie exists. In Google Chrome for instance the format is SQLite and for XP the cookies are stored in `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies`.

Comment: Thank you sir. you spent time writing such detailed explanation. Thanks again.