# Using cURL/php to get a page, but it's missing something

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, curl, get

I need to pull data from an external website (with a different domain).  A large portion of the data I'm attempting to retrieve doesn't show unless the user interacts (clicks) on an element, or alternately if a cookie is set.

I was trying to use curl with PHP, but I'm open to other options.  Is it possible to make a programmatic GET request that can process javascript during the request?

According to a post on this question curl can pass cookies, but the resulting behavior won't be sent back because it doesn't process the return data with js.

[setting cookie through curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007225/setting-cookie-through-curl)

Any other suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can work with cookies with curl. You can not, however, execute javascript with basic PHP functionality. The code at the question you linked is exactly how you can send a cookie with curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell there isn't much use for scraping data with a framework that can retrieve post-js-processed HTML output from a public facing webpage, and as such have abandoned progress on it.  I will update this post if I find a framework that allows for easy retrieval.